# How to disable SPA on flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I’m using flutter web on flutter ver2, and would like to know how to disable Single Page Application  styled development, because I’d like google to index all pages generated with flutter web.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve by myself with using named root. It was very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible currently.

Try looking at the `build/web` after building for the web. You will see only one HTML file called `index.html`. There are no literal pages.